# How do I position an image on each side of a header?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a picture of a tree on each side of my header, however I cannot figure out how to position the images correctly to where they are both above my navigation bar and positioned to the left and right of my header.

This jsfiddle shows it a bit better than the snippet.
https://jsfiddle.net/1qghboyh/

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

header {
 padding: 1em;
 color: white;
 background-color: #323241;
 clear: left;
 text-align: center;
}

footer {
 background-color: #339966;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 15px 3px rgba(31,31,31,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 15px 3px rgba(31,31,31,1);
 box-shadow: -1px 1px 15px 3px rgba(31,31,31,1);
 padding: 1em;
 color: white;
 background-color: #323241;
 clear: left;
 text-align: center;
}

.initials {
 float: left;
 opacity: .25;
}

.tree1 {
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.tree2 {
 float: right;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

.navigation-bar {
 -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 15px 3px rgba(31,31,31,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 15px 3px rgba(31,31,31,1);
 box-shadow: -1px 1px 15px 3px rgba(31,31,31,1);
 height: 3.2em;
 background: #339966;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 2px solid;
 border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.navigation-bar ul {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation-bar li {
 display: inline;
}

.navigation-bar li a {
 color: white;
 padding: 0px 30px;
 margin: 1em 0 0 -2px;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 height: 1.2em;
 line-height: 1.2em;
}

.navigation-bar li a.active{
 color: #111;
}

.navigation-bar li a:hover, a:focus {
 color: #111;
}

.columns {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 column-count: 3;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
 width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

.div1  {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 border-right: 2px solid;
 border-left: 2px solid;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="settings.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #323241">
<header>
 <div class="initials">#2 - C.C.</div>
 <img src="tree.jpg" class="tree1">
 <h1>Landscaping Company</h1>
 <img src="tree.jpg" class="tree2">
</header>
<div class="navigation-bar">
 <div id="navigation-container">
  <ul>
   <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="div1">
<div class="columns">
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Hemlock Landscapes has been caring for customers and their properties throughout the Chagrin Valley since 1981.
Our core values:
Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day
Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive
Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</p>

<p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.
Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.
This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.  If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.
Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfill our one company… total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:
Residential Landscape Maintenance
Landscape Design/Installation
Plant Health Care</p>

<p>Whether you are new to the Chagrin Valley, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Hemlock Landscapes makes it easy for you.</p>
<p>As Northeast Ohio Landscapers, Hemlock Landscapes has been caring for customers and their properties throughout the Chagrin Valley since 1981.
Our core values:
Bring a positive attitude with you each and every day
Work hard, pitch in, be helpful and productive
Be fair and respectful with all people in all encounters</p>

<p>When it comes to Residential Landscape Maintenance in Northeast Ohio, we have a pretty simple mission.
Our mission is to unite people in positive relationships to improve lives.
This includes not only our great customers but also our fantastic employees and vendors that we work with each and every day.  If we are not improving your life then we are not living up to our mission.
Experienced in every facet of the landscape industry, we fulfill our one company… total care philosophy by meeting your every need in the following areas:
Residential Landscape Maintenance
Landscape Design/Installation
Plant Health Care</p>

<p>Whether you are new to the Chagrin Valley, switching landscape service providers, or need to add a service to your existing account, Hemlock Landscapes makes it easy for you.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<footer>Copyright © Landscaping Company</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet is a little different than what I have, but I'm just focusing on the header for now and aligning the images to the left and right of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `img` tags within the `h1` tag and remove the floats from the images?

```
<h1><img src=...>Landscaping Company<img src=...></h1>
```

If you really want to use floats, then I've found that specifying the right float first in the HTML usually produces the desired result.

```
<img src="tree.jpg" class="tree2">
<img src="tree.jpg" class="tree1">
<h1>Landscaping Company</h1>
```

Comment: I guess I was trying to over-complicate things. I only added float because before it would put the images above and below the header, but that's because I didn't include them in the <h1></h1>.

Comment: <h1><img src="tree.jpg" class="tree1">Landscaping Company<img src="tree.jpg" class="tree2"></h1> This fixed it

Comment: If you need to vertically align the images with the text you can use the `vertical-align` property on the king's.

Comment: What if I wanted to position the images with more space between the title and the image. Would I have to use position: relative; left/right: 5px or something, or is there another way?

Comment: Add `padding-left` and `padding-right` to the images (as appropriate for the side they're on). Be sure to remove the floats.

Answer (score 2):

For one outcome you could use:

```
<header>
  <div class="initials">#2 - C.C.</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;float: left;">
    <img src="tree.jpg" class="tree1">
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block;float: right;">
    <img src="tree.jpg" class="tree2">
  </div>
  <h1 style="margin: .67em;">Landscaping Company</h1>
</header>
```

**Corrections and explanations:**

1. Your images were just plainly positioned inside the `<header>` container. That really limits what you can actually do with them, so I recommend you to always wrap them up a container. Moved them to their respective container.
2. After moving the images to their container, I cleared the block level behavior of the `<div>`'s by setting them to have a `display: inline-block`. Then I transferred the `float` properties to each of them respectively.
3. The `<h1>` tag has two CSS properties comming from *bootstrap.css* that override *normalize.css* setting for the margins. I modified it to be .67ems again, and the images fitted just perfectly along with the header.
4. The second image was positioned below the `<h1>` tag, so it was being pushed down by the header, because it has a block-level behavior. Be careful with the layout of your elements to avoid these kind of problems. Just FYI; (extracted from [MDN Re; Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)):

> Browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element. You can visualize them as a stack of boxes.

Now, if what you actually want is this:[image]
Modify your code to be like this instead:

```
<header>
  <div class="initials">#2 - C.C.</div>
    <div id="header-imgs">
      <div>
        <img src="tree.jpg" class="tree1">
      </div>
      <h1>Landscaping Company</h1>
      <div>
        <img src="tree.jpg" class="tree2">
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Remove the floats from the images, and add the following CSS:

`div#header-imgs, div#header-imgs > h1, div#header-imgs, div#header-imgs > div {
    display: inline-block;
}`

This second form works because of the following:

1. You are wrapping all elements in a single container, which have them go in the correct order in the DOM Flow (img 1 goes before the header, the header before img 2 and you can guess the last one).
2. Removing the floats will return the images to the DOM Flow. Also just FYI (again), if the floated elements are the only child of their parent containers, then this will collapse said parent. This leads to horrible headaches if you ever have to check for broken layout here that is screwing up a whole project (say, HTML designed letters).
3. The `display: inline-block` will have all three elements stacked at the same level, and they will keep the block behavior that lets you do marvels with them (e.g. top-bottom margins).

Comment: This should be Best Answer. Less hacky than the currently accepted best answer, and also a lot more comprehensive/informative.

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? Those picture placeholders look a hell of a lot prettier than what I currently have on Firefox.

Comment: @Hashim, I'm using Google Chrome, version 53.0.2785.143. And thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 2):

As the tree is not actually "content" and more a decoration I would set it as a background image using CSS. Any screen readers etc won't be confused by a meaningless image tag with no `alt` attribute.

```css
h1::before, h1::after
{
  content:'';
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100); /*use tree here*/
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}

h1::before
{
  float:left;
}

h1::after
{
  float:right;
  clear:right;
}

h1
{ 
  text-align: center;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some Content</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:inline` attribute to the `header tag` will give you the expected,try This

```
h1
{
  display : inline;
}
```